# Transformação de string em python

Tags: python-3.x

Por que desta forma não há erro:

```
print(f'Seu nome possui {len(nome.replace(" ", ""))} letras')
```

Mas desta há:

```
print(f'Seu nome possui {len(nome.replace(' ', ''))} letras')
```

Python não trata aspas simples e aspas duplas como sinonimos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problema

Aqui ele entende que todo conteúdo é uma `string` completa, já que você inicia com aspas simples e finaliza com aspas simples, e ele entende as aspas duplas como parte da string, já que você inicio a instrução com aspas simples.

```
print(f'Seu nome possui {len(nome.replace(" ", ""))} letras')
```

Aqui a situação é diferente, ele interpreta a instrução como se fosse passada 3 `strings` diferentes separadas com espaço, já que você iniciou com aspas simples, ele espera o final com aspas simples.

```
print(f'Seu nome possui {len(nome.replace(' ', ''))} letras')
```

## Como ficou separada as strings

**String 1:** 'Seu nome possui {len(nome.replace('

**String 2:** ', '

**String 3:** '))} letras'

## Um exemplo

Vou da um exemplo mais simples para enxergar o problema

É como se você quisesse fazer o `print` da seguinte forma:

```
print('oi' 'eu' 'sou' 'assim')
```

E o certo seria

```
print('oi eu sou assim')
```